# python find image with path in file

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to find svgs or pngs withing a file. The images are in a attribue v="..."

A part of the file looks like this:

```
<symbol alpha="1" type="marker" name="0">
<layer pass="0" class="SvgMarker" locked="0">
<prop k="angle" v="0"/>
<prop k="fill" v="#000000"/>
<prop k="name" v="../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg"/>
<prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
<prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
<prop k="outline" v="#000000"/>
<prop k="outline-width" v="1"/>
<prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
<prop k="size" v="hello.png"/>
<prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
</layer>
```

I'd like to get a list like:

['../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg','hello.png']

My python code:

```
import re
projectFile = open("project.xml", "r")
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=v\=").+(\.svg|\.png)(?="/>)')

for line in projectFile:
    result = regex.findall(line)            
    for filename in result:
        print filename
```

I've tested my regex with http://pythex.org/ which work fine but in python console the result is just `.svg` it seems the capturing group `(\.svg|\.png)` is interpreted differently. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using regex a requirement? In case it isn't, an easier and cleaner approach would be to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

As it seems that the URIs you want appear in `prop` elements where `k="name"`, you could use [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) to do something like:

```
from lxml import etree
f = etree.parse(projectFile)
root = f.getroot()
# This will give you a list with all prop elements that contain the URIs you want in the v attribute
elements = root.xpath("//prop[@k='name']")
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your reply! regex is not a requirement. Two questions when I print elements or loop through it I get `<Element prop at 0x7ff43ae3bab8>` what does it mean -  and how to print the found items? And how would I restrict this to svg and png?

Comment: These which you are printing are the elements that contain the URIs you want (e.g. `<prop k="name" v="../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg"/>`)

Now that you have those elements, all you need to do is to access their `v` attribute, which would give you the URI (`"../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg"`)

Answer (score 0):

This fails because you are using `regex.findall` and you have a group in your regex: `(\.svg|\.png)`. If you change that to non-capturing group `(?:\.svg|\.png)`, then `findall` will find the whole match.

See the [re.findall doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall), which says:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.

```
>>> line = '<prop k="name" v="../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg"/>'
>>>
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?<=v\=").+(\.svg|\.png)(?="/>)')
>>> regex.findall(line)
['.svg']
>>>
>>> regex2 = re.compile(r'(?<=v\=").+(?:\.svg|\.png)(?="/>)')
>>> regex2.findall(line)
['../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg']
```

Or you could use `re.search`, which will return a Match object and give you more control:

```
>>> match = regex.search(line)
>>>
>>> match.group(0)
'../Downloads/Inkscape_vectorisation_test.svg'
>>>
>>> match.group(1)
'.svg'
```

**On the other hand...**

Regex is only a half-solution. If you use an XML parser instead, it will take case of text encoding, escape sequences, multiline tags, different quoting styles. So, if you want a more robust solution, don't use regexes here at all.

Comment: zvone, I'm just starting with python and your answer helped me a lot. can you say why a png reference is not found? It seams the png part of the group does not match.

Comment: @tBook It should find both png and svg. With your example, if you just modify the regex it should work.